# Font Issue - Javafx in Ubuntu

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I have faced problem in Javafx with font in both Windows and Ubuntu.
In Ubuntu, Some Lable text are not display but I check in windows OS it will work perfect.
Any Solution Regarding this Problem.??
Here I have Uploaded two image...

This image was in  Ubuntu.

[image]

This Image was in windows.

[image]

in both there are isssue in font.
plz help me .. what are  issue.??

Comment: What kind of issue do you mean? Ellipsis, smaller font or something with Gujarati rendering?

Comment: Some text in label are cut in ubuntu. but window  that are not cut.

Answer (score 2):

Are the two systems running at the same screen DPI? If not you'll need to scale it. You can test the screen DPI with Screen.getPrimary().getDpi();

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getDpi()